# Elegant way to handle exceptions in Test cases of MVVM Light's ViewModel

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, mstest

I am working on a wpf application using mvvm light toolkit. Whenever something goes outside the business logic we'll prompt the user with the message box and I send the message from view model to view using

Messenger.Default.Send(Token,"Some text message here");

Now I am writing test cases for view models and in some cases, Code Under Test is linked with such message calls. These are exceptions to me but test cases does not treat them exception as long as it is not being called by throw exception("message")

Suggestions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to verify that the business logic detects a problem and the correct message box is being "shown" in your test case.  If that's so, here's what I do:

- Instead of using messaging, create a UserNotificationService and IUserNotificationService interface.  The concrete implementation would be something like:

> ```
> public class UserNotificationService : IUserNotificationService
> {
>    public void MessageBox(string message)
>    {
>       // code to make the message box pop up goes here
>    }
> }
> ```

- Inject `IUserNotificationService` in your view model's constructor (you already have `SimpleIoC` since you are using `mvvm-light`) and use it to communicate with the user.
- When unit testing, either mock the `IUserNotificationService` or create a new `FakeUserNotificationService` class that is capable of verifying the correct message/error was sent.  Put that in the constructor of the view model being tested.

> ```
> public class FakeUserNotificationService : IUserNotificationService
> {
>    public void MessageBox(string message)
>    {
>       LastMessage = message;
>    }
>
>    public string LastMessage {get; set;}
> }
> ```

In your test:

```
var ns = new FakeUserNotificationService();
var viewModel = new MyViewModel(ns);

viewModel.DoSomethingBad();

Assert.AreEqual(ns.LastMessage, "expected error message");
```

Comment: Seems neat but why would this be better than just registering for messages sent by viewmodel in certain conditions? That ensures message was indeed sent and "exception" catched. Besides that, anything related to UI (like showing messagebox) should not be injected in VM at all, right?

Comment: I originally did things this way because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992200/mvvm-unit-tests-message-bus-only-works-once.  It's since been fixed (I think) but it also means I can use Moq.Verify() consistently and not have to fuss with messaging at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are sending message from VM to View, which handles the actual "showing logic", then just register for the message in your VM tests and verify that it has been sent/received.  For example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SendSomethingBadHappenedMessageTest()
{
    const string expected = "oh noes!";
    string actual = null;

    // Register for message to ensure message was sent from VM
    Messenger.Default.Register<SomethingBadHappenedMessage>(this, 
        message => actual = message.Message);

    // Assuming command triggers Messenger.Send
    _viewModel.SomethingBadHappenedCommand.Execute(expected);  

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

If you test for exceptions, just mark test method with `ExpectedException` attribute.